# output more than limited results from a form request

Tags: python, html, forms, curl, web-scraping

I have the following script that posts a search terms into a form and retrieves results:

```
import mechanize

url = "http://www.taliesin-arlein.net/names/search.php"
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False) # ignore robots
br.open(url)
br.select_form(name="form")
br["search_surname"] = "*"
res = br.submit()
content = res.read()
with open("surnames.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(content)
```

however the rendered web page, and hence script here limits the search to 250 results. Is there any way I can bypass this limit and retrieve all results?

Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question: the web request return just 250 results?

Comment: You have 2 possibility: 1 write a mail to the webmaster of www.taliesin-arlein.net and ask all results; 2 hack the site and steal all surname.... Seriously: it seams to me that the script dosn't take any argument to change the max size of the answer.

Comment: lol don't want to steal anything. I assumed since it is possible to get all the data by doing repeated queries as the website allows, then maybe there would be some way of doing it all in one. and yes the web request only returns the first 250 results.

Comment: Unfortunately the form use a wildcards and not sequence or interval definition. You can do that by take last answer and do an other call by move the wildcard. It is a little bit tedious and not really interesting, but it should work. I don't thing I'll file an answer for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply iterate over possible prefixes to get around the limit. There is 270,000 names and a limit of 250 results per query, therefore you need to make at least 1080 requests, there are 26 letters in the alphabet so if we assume there is an even distribution this would mean we would need to use a little over 2 letters as a prefix (log(1080)/log(26)), however it is unlikely to be that even (how many people have surnames starting with ZZ after all).

To get around this we use a modified depth first search like so:

```
import string
import time
import mechanize

def checkPrefix(prefix):
    #Return list of names with this prefix.
    url = "http://www.taliesin-arlein.net/names/search.php"
    br = mechanize.Browser()
    br.open(url)
    br.select_form(name="form")
    br["search_surname"] = prefix+'*'
    res = br.submit()
    content = res.read()
    return extractSurnames(content)

def extractSurnames(pageText):
    #write function to extract text from html


Q=[x for x in string.ascii_lowercase]
listOfSurnames=[]
while Q:
    curPrefix=Q.pop()
    print curPrefix
    curSurnames=checkPrefix(curPrefix)
    if len(curSurnames)<250:
        #store surnames could also write to file.
        listOfSurnames+=curSurnames
    else:
        #We clearly didnt get all of the names need to subdivide more
        Q+=[curPrefix+x for x in string.ascii_lowercase]
    time.sleep(5) # Sleep here to avoid overloading the server for other people.
```

Thus we query more in places where there are too many results to be displayed, but we do not query ZZZZ if there is less than 250 surnames that start with ZZZ (or shorter). Without knowing how skewed the name distribution is, hard to estimate how long this will take but the 5 seconds sleep multiplied by 1080 is 1.5 hours or so so you are probably looking at at least half a day if not longer.

Note: This could be made more efficient by declaring the browser globally, however whether this is appropriate depends on where this code will be placed.

Comment: wow - this is great. will have to absorb it, but you have even thought of uneven distributions which would inevitably come into play. thanks very much - this will make for good reading.